# How to find median of column in pyspark?

Tags: python, numpy, pyspark, median

I have a spark data frame

```
df = 
   a     b     c     d
0  12  12.0   car  bike
1  20  20.5   car  alto
2  15  12.0  bike   car
3  25    25  bike  jeep
```

I want to find the median of a column 'a'. I couldn't find an appropriate way to find the median, so used the normal python NumPy function to find the median but I was getting an error as below:-

```
import numpy as np
median = df['a'].median()
```

error:-

```
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

Expected output:-

```
17.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use precentile_approx like this,

```
df.agg(F.expr("percentile_approx('a', 0.5)")).show()
```